# Create Array from list of indices/values

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, conversion

Is there is a performat way to convert something like

```
{{0,0},a},{{0,1},c},{{1,0},d},{{1,1},e}
```

into

> ```
> {{a,b},{c,d}}
> ```

The indices are not always orderes and the only solution I can think of is searching for the maximum indices, create a matrix filled with 0 and use map afterwards to modify the matrix. 
Is there is a better way?

Thank you,
 Martin

Comment: I assume that when you write  `{{0,0},a},{{0,1},c},{{1,0},d},{{1,1},e}` you actually mean `{{{0, 0}, a}, {{0, 1}, b}, {{1, 0}, c}, {{1, 1}, d}}`, Please check that the input is correct.

Answer (score 13):

```
spec = {{{0, 0}, a}, {{0, 1}, b}, {{1, 0}, c}, {{1, 1}, d}};

Normal @ SparseArray[# + 1 -> #2 & @@@ spec]
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}}

Answer (score 8):

Also possible:

```
r = {{{0, 0}, a}, {{0, 1}, c}, {{1, 0}, d}, {{1, 1}, e}};
SparseArray[r[[All, 1]] + 1 -> r[[All, 2]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Array[{#1, #2} &, {2, 2}]-1)/.Rule@@@list
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}}

where

```
list={{{0, 0}, a}, {{0, 1}, b}, {{1, 0}, c}, {{1, 1}, d}};
```

Comment: I think you misinterpret the question. The index may not be limited by 2.